# Send a PDF attachment in email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have SharePoint designer workflow, one of action is sending email!

How can I send a PDF file as attachment not as a link in **email** action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole premis of SharePoint is not to distribute documents around the organisation using mail, as such it is not possible to send a mail with an attachment. The best you can do out of the box is to send a link to the document - otherwise you would need to either use a 3rd party solution or go by some form of powershell script.

Comment: Sometimes it's unfeasible to give access to all those recipients to the SP Site, and mail is just more convenient

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do that, but there are third-party tools to help you.
Check this short video: [Send email with attachment to external users using workflow in SharePoint 2013 or Office 365](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQN1ZldtW9c)